# How to break up complex type aliases in haskell?

Tags: haskell, sudoku

I came across this very old sudoku code which seems greek to me coz of mainly this ugly type

```
type T = (Int,Int) -> [Int]
```

To understand this function for instance

```
mark :: ((Int,Int),Int) -> T -> T
mark (p@(i,j),n) s q@(x,y) =
  if p==q then [n] else
  if x==i || y==j || e x i && e y j then delete n $ s q else s q
  where e a b = div (a-1) 3==div (b-1) 3
```

I can replace the T with the actual type

```
mark :: ((Int,Int),Int) -> (Int,Int)->[Int] -> (Int,Int)->[Int]
mark (p@(i,j),n) s q@(x,y) =
```

Now the type arguments don't seem to line up properly. p matches perfectly, but i get confused with "s". If I jump into the call for mark it's like this.....here the list I can easily see it's array of key value pairs with keys like (1,2) etc. These have been filtered for blanks or zeros in sudoku.

```
input :: String -> (Int,Int) -> [Int]
input s = foldr mark (const [1..9]) $
   [(p,n) | (p,n) <- zip idx $ map read $ lines s >>= words, n>0]
```

The mark function is called with this list and accumulator which is a function (const [1..9]). This doesn't fit the type signature.

```
mark :: ((Int,Int),Int) -> (Int,Int)->[Int] -> (Int,Int)->[Int]
```

Problem with the code is that I can't see the actual result of the mark function which I still don't understand. When it's passed to a third function it gets some output. Any explanation on how to understand this sphagetti code?

Comment: Put the `T`s in parentheses first, then perform the substitution.  It should be `mark :: ((Int, Int), Int) -> ((Int, Int) -> [Int]) -> ((Int, Int) -> [Int])`.

Comment: why parentheses are required? I didn't say type T = ((Int,Int) -> [Int])

Comment: The types `a -> b -> c` and `(a -> b) -> c` are different, the first is not different from `a -> (b -> c)`.  The `->` is right-associative, so the parentheses matter.

Comment: If it was right associative I would have got...((Int,Int),Int )-> ((Int,Int) ->  ([Int] -> ((Int,Int) -> [Int])))

Comment: No, you would have `((Int, Int), Int) -> (T) -> (T) ~ ((Int, Int), Int) -> (T) -> ((Int, Int) -> [Int]) ~ ((Int, Int), Int) -> (T) -> (Int, Int) -> [Int] ~ ((Int, Int), Int) -> ((Int, Int) -> [Int]) -> (Int, Int) -> [Int]`.  I would recommend copy/pasting this into your editor and splitting it up on the `~`s to read it better, but this is the substitution that GHC will do to arrive at the final type.  Note that you end up with essentially 3 arguments, the `((Int, Int), Int)`, `((Int, Int) -> [Int])`, and `(Int, Int)`, to return a `[Int]`.

Comment: @AnimeshSaxena "Why are the parentheses needed?" Answer: because Haskell does the sane thing and uses syntactic substitution, not string interpolation. One can't write `type Foo = eger` and use `IntFoo` in place of `Integer`, either, and thank goodness for that!

Comment: This is the kind of moment where naming things well can make all the difference.

Comment: Ok I got most of it. I didn't get the last part where you remove the parenthesis from (T).  ((Int, Int), Int) -> ((Int,Int)->[Int]) -> ((Int,Int)->[Int]). In your solution the last argument has parenthesis removed and it splits up into two parts. So why this selective choice, coz both 2nd and third arguments were T? Sorry if this is stretching your patience.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A value of this type

```
type T = (Int,Int) -> [Int]
```

maps the coordinates of any sudoku cell `(x,y) :: (Int,Int)` into a set of the possible values such cell might have (represented as a list of digits `[Int]`).

The function `const [0..9]` maps any cell into the set of all digits. It acts as the initial state for a sudoku solver: at the beginning, assume any cell may have any digit.

Comment: In other words, instead of `T`, a better name would have been `Optioner` or even `Solver`.

Comment: So as per the mapping I would get something like this....p = ((1,2),6) (for example). s = function which takes two ints and gives out an array of ints. This seems to hold for (const [1..9]) coz if I do (const [1..9]) (2,3) it will give out [1..9] which is array of ints. Still there is confusion about q. I am not passing q when i am calling mark via foldr. What is q? How is it passed in the call?

Comment: @AnimeshSaxena True, `foldr` is not passing `q` to `mark`. But `mark` is returning a `T`, which is a function that does take `q` (a pair) and returns a list. Instead of writing `mark p s = \q -> ... some list` which is clearer, the author wrote the equivalent `mark p s q = ... some list`.